# Sonata Media exception 'The uploaded file is not found'

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

Uploading files more than 2MB size in Sonata Admin (v3.28.0) with Sonata Media Bundle (v3.10.0) in Symfony (v2.8.32) application results in error:

```
The uploaded file is not found
```

I just didn't found this kind of error message on stackoverflow, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The `UploadException` itself in my case was caused by error with status `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` which is caused by the value of `upload_max_filesize` php directive, which default is 2MB.

You can change it in your php.ini file:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files
upload_max_filesize = 20M
; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

Then you should restart your web server like this:

**ubuntu**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**centos**

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

or

```
service httpd restart
```

**macos**

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

If it doesn't help, you can check if the change was applied by including `phpinfo();` to your script.

In my case the value didn't changed, no matter how hard I tried.

Finally I had to restart my system to solve the problem.